# Chef: Initialize new linux user if it doesn't already exist

Tags: linux, chef-infra

I'm trying to use Chef to create a new user and expire the user's password if the user doesn't already exist.

I've managed to do it by using a bash script and executing it on the agent server but I'd like a cleaner way.

Current Bash Script:

http://i.gyazo.com/fdd49630f58f9b0e0acdc324143e3481.png

Wanted Use in the recipe:

```
inituser do
    username => "username"
    password => "password"
    group => "group":
end
```

With the above code creating a new user if it doesn't already exist and expiring its password.

Thank you!

UPDATE: Sorry for my poor communication but what I'm wanting to do is have my own custom resource which will "parse" the username, password, and group to the my prewritten bash resource I have above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use the user resource to create a new user.

```
user "newuser" do
  supports :manage_home => true
  home "/home/newuser"
  shell "/bin/bash"
  password "$1$JJsvHslV$szsCjVEroftprNn4JHtDi."
  not_if "getent passwd newuser"
end
```

Note that the password is a password shadow hash and can be generated as follows:

`openssl passwd -1 "theplaintextpassword"`

For more info: http://docs.opscode.com/resource_user.html

Comment: But that will reset the password of an existing user, I don't want that

Comment: @Jahaja I don't use chef, and am not that familiar with its syntax, but shouldn't that be not_if instead of only_if?

Comment: No, the usual way to indicate an error on *nix is a non-zero return value.

Comment: You've changed the question quite radically and it doesn't make any sense why you can't use what I've answered with. Why roll your own that does the same thing?